# Population and sample with very different means: why is that so?

Tags: bayesian, sample

[image: http://postimg.org/image/vppji4o3r/]

I have a problem with determining the effect of sample size on the shape of a prior probability distribution. The parameter values are on the $x$ and the prob on the $y$ axis. The right curve consists of individuals (smaller sample size), while the left consists of colonies (with larger sample size).

I just don't know why the position of the mean changes. I expected that the larger sample should have peak more (central limit) but not that the mean would shift. Could somebody tell me whether there is any mechanism which would result in the behaviour seen on the picture?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the characteristic you are trying to assess is, but there are two possibilities that I can see based on your description: (1) the small sample of individuals was randomly different from expected (solution, take multiple small samples of individuals and compare); (2) the characteristic or its meaning in some way changes when measured for individuals or groups/colonies.

An example of this second issue might be income. The average income of a group of individuals selected from a number of countries could easily differ from the average per capita income of each of those countries. This is because the average income of individuals likely only includes individuals who are eligible to earn income, whereas the per capita income may be calculated including all individuals many of whom may be basically ineligible to earn income (ex. too old/young; on disability; etc).